# 16.04 NFS Mount Errors with "mount.nfs: NFS URLs are not supported"

Tags: 16.04, nfs

I just bought a WD MyCloud 4TB NAS, and on the network 4x Ubuntu 1604. have Win 7, Win 10, android, and iOS.

Both Windows and Android seem to connect fine.

I am running KDE on 16.04 on my Ubuntu machines
Installed nfs-common

When I use Dophin, I can navigate to the Shares on WD, which have NFS Enabled, and could even do this before enabling NFS, however, I want to run backup scripts, and copies from the Ubuntu OS, to the WD filesystem and wish to mount the WDFS to be able to do that.

I have tried mounting the drive 
sudo mount -o rw,vers=2  ~/shares

mount address takes the form "nfs://" + ip_address + "/nfs/" + share name

However, what I get as a response is:

"mount.nfs: NFS URLs are not supported"

Any ideas as I get nothing meaningful when I search for this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Hi Alw,

try the address without the nfs:// ..

It should be like this:


`[/etc/fstab]
ip_address:/path/to/remote/nfs/share /local/mount/point nfs options 0 0`

*options* - i use `noauto, rw` (but feel free to use whatever you'd like)

Let me know, if it helped.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

The manual command line command you'd want to use:

`sudo mount [Share IP]:/share/path /mount/path`

The `/etc/fstab` line you'd want to use:

`[Share IP]:/share/path    /mount/path    nfs    auto    0    0`